# Warning: Missing argument 2 &3 for Varien_Simplexml_Config::loadString() errors in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9.3.6, simplexml

I am getting these errors in system.log. Magento 1.9.3.6

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Varien_Simplexml_Config::loadString(), called in /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 786 and defined in /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 507
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for Varien_Simplexml_Config::loadString(), called in /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 786 and defined in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 507

I tried debugging them by adjusting the loadstring function in the config.php file:

```
public function loadString($string,$el,$filePath)
    {
        if (is_string($string)) {
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
            if (false === $xml) {
              //$errors = libxml_get_errors();
              echo "<br>";$filePath; die;
            }
            if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
                $this->_xml = $xml;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Anybody a clue on how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: The errors state your missing parameter 2 and 3 when that string is being requested im assuming you have a custom module which is trying to access this function withou the relevant params

Comment: @DavaGordon Thanks for your reply, Can you help me how can i fix it, have tried to disable some module, still facing the issue

Comment: Disable all none magento extensions to see if the error still occures if so you can then check your theme to see if that is the cause if not it could possibly be a core issue if so then you may be able to raise a ticket on github regarding it